# Extract Outlook Contacts using R

Tags: r, outlook, rdcomclient

I am trying to query Outlook Contacts and extract them all in a csv file using R programming language.
I have a example piece of code:

```
#####################################################
library(RDCOMClient)
## init com api
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
olFolderContacts <- 10

# get the namespace
ns <- OutApp$GetNamespace("MAPI")
# get the contact folder
folderContacts = ns$GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
# get the contact list
folderItems = folderContacts$Items()
i = 0
# get the first contact
itemObj = folderItems$Item(i+1)
#####################################################
# That's here that it fails
#####################################################
ContactName <- itemObj$GetElement()$Name()
#####################################################
```

The idea is that the folder contains items which are of different type.
How to query the Object COM interface to get the object type or Class and how to invoke the methods related to it?

Thanks,

Maurizio.

Comment: welcome to SO ;)

Comment: please describe the error you get?

Comment: I managed to fix it...

Comment: Here is the code:

Comment: `code` library(RDCOMClient)

## init com
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
olFolderContacts <- 10

# get the namespace
ns <- OutApp$GetNamespace("MAPI")
# get the contact folder
folderContacts = ns$GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
# get the contact list
folderItems = folderContacts$Items()
i <- 0
for (i in 1:folderItems$Count()){
  itemObj = folderItems$Item(i)
  ContactFirstName <- itemObj$firstname()
  ContactLastName <- itemObj$lastname()
  ContactEmail <- itemObj$email1address()
  print( paste( ContactEmail, ContactFirstName, ContactLastName, sep = " - "))
}

Comment: it's better if you answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,own%20question%20at%20any%20time.

Comment: also code in comments can be done with `

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to extract the list of my contacts with the following code :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
Application <- RDCOMClient::COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
ns <- Application$GetNamespace("MAPI") 
foldContact <- ns$GetDefaultFolder(10) 
colItems <- foldContact$Items()$Restrict("[MessageClass]='IPM.Contact'") 
nb_Contact <- colItems$Count()
list_Info_Contact <- list()

for(i in 1 : nb_Contact)
{
  creation_Time <- colItems[[i]]$CreationTime()
  full_Name <- colItems[[i]]$FullName() 
  list_Temp_Info <- list(creation_Time = creation_Time, full_Name = full_Name)
  list_Info_Contact[[i]] <- list_Temp_Info
}
```